# How to change iOS button size based on titleLabel length

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

My buttons don't resize based on the text in their titleLabel. All of the titleLabel text is displayed, but it goes outside the bounds of the button

[image]

My buttons are in a stackview in a xib cell. The xib cell also has a label above the stackview.

I have two classes: ViewController (tableview and datasource), ViewCell (button outlets and actions)

ViewController code:
In my cellForRowAt method:

```
cell.choice1Button.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
cell.choice2Button.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
cell.choice3Button.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
cell.choice1Button.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
cell.choice2Button.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
cell.choice3Button.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0

cell.conceptLabel.text = question["concept"]!
cell.choice1Button.setTitle(question["choice1"]!, for: .normal)
cell.choice2Button.setTitle(question["choice2"]!, for: .normal)
cell.choice3Button.setTitle(question["choice3"]!, for: .normal)

cell.mcTableCellDelegate = self
```

I want the buttons to resize in height and for the text to wrap based on how long the titleLabel text is.  Is this a constraints issue?

Comment: "All of the titleLabel text is displayed, but it goes outside the bounds of the button" Really? How do you know?

Comment: @matt I edited my post and added an image